# while iterating over a pandas Series, query an SQLite database with each member of the Series

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a pandas Series made from the following python dictionary, so:

```
gr8 = {'ERF13' : 'AT2G44840', 'BBX32' : 'AT3G21150', 'NAC061' : 'AT3G44350', 'NAC090' : 'AT5G22380', 'ERF019' : 'AT1G22810'}
gr8obj = pd.Series(gr8)
```

( where I have previously imported pandas as pd )

I have an SQLite database, AtRegnet.db

I want to iterate over the pandase Series, gr8obj, and query the database, AtRegnet.db, for each member of the series.

This is what I have tried:

```
for i in gr8obj:
    resdf = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM AtRegNet WHERE TargetLocus = ?' (i), con=sqlite3.connect("/home/anno/SQLiteDBs/AtRegnet.db"))
    fresdf = resdf.append(resdf)

fresdf
```

( the table in the AtRegnet.db that I want is AtRegNet and the column I am searching on is called TargetLocus. )

I know that when I work on the SQLite3 database directly with a SQL command,

```
select * from AtRegNet where TargetLocus="AT3G23230"
```

that I get back 80 lines from the database. (AT3G23230 is one of members of gr8obj)

Comment: Amend also the loop logics to init `fresdf` outside the loop and append `resdf` to `fresdf` instead of `resdf` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a f-string. And the value for TargetLocus in your query should also be in quotes

```
resdf = pd.read_sql(f'''SELECT * FROM AtRegNet WHERE TargetLocus = \'{i}\'''')
```

Comment: Coool !  Just added a comma and then the connection to the end of your command, and along with SeaBean's comment of initializing a data frame, fresdf, before the for loop and then appending resdf to fresdf and all works very well.